# write every possible char into a file

Tags: c++, unicode, char, fstream

I want to write every character that exists into a file. I guess unicode has the most complete set of characters, but I can't quite tell. Can you help me out with this? I'm working in C++. This code seems to "only" write the ASCII set of chars (or am I wrong?). Thx for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

wofstream wOutStream;
wOutStream.open("myFile.txt");

wchar_t myChar = 0;
do {
    wOutStream << myChar << " ";
    myChar++;
} while (myChar != 0);

wOutStream.close();

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't just increment the character and hope for it to successfully iterate over the entirety of the UNICODE character space. There are literally billions of possible characters, but [only a fraction are allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).

Comment: Unicode chars need to follow certain bit patterns, as mentioned only a fraction of all the possible numbers that would fit in.

Comment: Okay, but can you explain me a way to do this?

Comment: @KilianHe the best way is to get a Unicode database that tells you which characters are defined, although it may get out of date.

Comment: @tadman, not billions...U+0000 to U+10FFFF is 1,114,112 possible but not all are allocated.

Comment: @MarkRansom I would really appreciate a lot if you would go into detail with that. sounds very promising! I'm a novice programmer so bear with me :)

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ah, I just checked and the 6-byte variant of UTF-8 was killed off a while ago. Good to know. [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=UTF-32) doesn't use the entire 32-bit number space, which is where I was thinking "billions" from.

Comment: @MarkTolonen can you tell me how to iterate through all those chars and skip the ones that aren't allocated?

Comment: Please keep in mind that `wchar_t` and "wide" streams in general don't have anything to do with Unicode. You actually will have to do quite a bit of work to use them and Unicode in a compatible way, and about 10x that amount of work to do the same in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: @KilianHe, You need some kind of Unicode database to determine what is used and what isn't.  In Python, for example, there is a `unicodedata` module where you can query what a Unicode codepoint represents and make decisions.  Also, writing Unicode codepoints to a file isn't possible.  You have to pick an encoding.  UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, and UTF-32BE are typical options.  Would you accept a Python solution? :)

Comment: @ MarkTolonen yes a Python solution would be dandy aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an open-ended question, the exact answer depends on how ambitious you are. So I'm not going to post a program, but just list the basic steps:

- Unicode allocates characters to numbers (called *code points*), for instance "A" is allocated to nr 65, commonly written in hexadecimal as U+0041. It also defines the name and a lot of other properties. For instance "A" is called "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A", it's lower case version is "a", it's part of a left-to-right language etc.
- But on it's own it does **not** specify how that character is written to a file. For that you have to pick an encoding. A common encoding are UTF-8, it should be easy to find the code to encode a code point to bytes. And if you open your text file, then your editor also needs to understand that encoding (shouldn't be a problem for UTF-8).
- Specifically for C++, when writing UTF-8 I would open a narrow output stream (`std::ofstream`) and write the bytes. C++ in principle has no support for writing Unicode files. Your program would roughly look like this.

  ```
  for (unsigned int codePoint = 0; codePoint < 0x110000; ++codePoint)
  {
      std::string utf8 = encode_utf8(codePoint);
      outStream << utf8 << " ";
  }
  ```

  Maybe add a newline every 256 characters or so.
- There are 17 *planes* of 2^16 code points. many commonly used characters are in the first plane. You can either print the first plane only (U+0000 to U+FFFF), or print all code points (U+0000 to U+10FFFF). Some of the planes don't have assigned characters yet.
- Do you want to print the *assigned* code points only? In that case you have to download the list from the Unicode consortium and parse it. There is no formula which yields the allocated code points. Or as others pointed out, you can use a language with those tables built-in, like Python or Java.
- And finally, some of the ranges are reserved for *private use*. You may choose to skip those as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like C++ is a poor choice for this task? What will an unassigned code point look like? If it's an empty string I could check that before writing it to the file. What happens when I try to access something within the range for private use?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to do a bit of research into what Unicode is. C++ is fine, but it will be a bit more work. Unassigned code points and private use characters will probably show up as invalid characters, how exactly depends on how you display the file. For instance,  is in a private use block, ͸ is not assigned.